# How many critical points does the function $f (x) = |x^2 − x − 6|$ have on the interval $[−3, 1]$?

Tags: calculus

> How many critical points does the function $$f (x) = |x^2 − x − 6|$$ have on the interval $[−3, 1]$?

So I take the first derivative of the function and I get
$$\frac{(x+2)(x-3)(2x-1)}{|x^2-x-6|},$$
which would give me three critical points, but the answer is two? Does it have something to do with the end points? Thanks.

Comment: That seems a very messy way to take a derivative indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the numerator, you have three potential critical points: -2, 3, and $\frac{1}{2}$. What interval are you looking at?

Comment: Ahhh! I see, 3 is not in the interval, so it doesn't count. But aren't endpoints critical points as well?

Comment: @user115174 the definition of a critical point is that the derivative at that point is zero. The endpoints of a interval are only endpoints if they satisfy this.

Note that they can still be minima or maxima of a function, even if they're not critical points. This is why when finding the extreme values of a function, you have to look at the endpoints separately.